# Instagram API endpoint no longer returns data

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Since 2 days (1 June 2016), endpoint of my website has stopped receiving data.

What I'm trying to do is get latest photos of a location ID, using the following API endpoint:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/108716935824604/media/recent?access_token=MY_KEY`

No matter what the location ID is, The data returns is empty.

```
{"pagination": {}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}
```

What has gone wrong?

Comment: Instagram updated there api process: http://developers.instagram.com/